# Extracting certain levels more than others

Tags: r, random, sampling

I'm trying to simulate the sampling of wildlife from a given site. I've made a species list that contains all species that can be found at that site and their associated rarity.

```
df <- data.frame(rarity = rep(c('common', 'uncommon', 'rare'), each = 2),
                 species = letters[1:6])
print(df)
    rarity species
1   common       a
2   common       b
3 uncommon       c
4 uncommon       d
5     rare       e
6     rare       f
```

I then create another data set based on the random sampling of rows from `df`.

```
df.sampled <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), 30, T),]
```

The trouble is that this isn't realistic; you're not going to encounter `rare` species as frequently as `uncommon` species as `common` species. For example, 6 out of 10 animals encountered should be `common`, 3 out of 10 animals should be `uncommon`, and 1 out of 10 animals shouldbe `rare`. Here, we're getting all three rarities at equal frequency:

```
df.matrix <- matrix(NA, ncol = 3, nrow = 1000)
for(i in 1:1000){
  df.sampled <- df[sample(1:6, 30, T),]
  df.matrix[i,] <- c(table(df.sampled$rarity))
}
apply(df.matrix, 2, mean)
```

Is there a way I can sample particular rows more often than others given their rarity? I have a feeling `qnorm()` should be used, but I could be wrong...

Comment: See `prob` argument of `sample`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your line edited to use the `prob` argument with example values of 0.6 for common, 0.3 for uncommon and 0.1 for rare:

```
prob_vec <- c(0.6, 0.6, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.1)
df.sampled <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), 30, T, prob = prob_vec),]
```

df.sampled now has a more uneven distribution.

Comment: That was embarrassingly simple, but that made it work. Thanks!